# Confused on what this MIPS assignment is asking

Tags: mips, qtspim, spim

I'm not asking for a solution, but i am completely lost on what they are asking for. Can anyone explain to me what they are looking for?

> In MIPS/QTSPim, write a subprogram convert_number that converts a
>   string with a C-style integer literal to a value.  Implements a main
>   program that prompts the user for two C-style unsigned numbers, calls
>   convert_number to convert the strings to their numerical values, and
>   outputs the sum of the numbers.
>
> **convert_number(string, eos)**
>
> - **string** contains a well-formed C-style literal(number)
> - **eos** is the end of the string character  return value:
>
> ---
>
> 1. C-style integer number:
>
>    - a. Decimal number starts with a digit 1 .. 9, follows by digits 0 .. 9
>    - b. Octal number starts with digit 0, follows by digits 0 .. 7
>    - c. Hexadecimal number starts with 0x, follows by digits 0 .. 9, a .. f, where a=10, …, f=15
> 2. The maximum input will be 10. Use read string `syscall` to get the input.
> 3. No error handlings are required, eg. invalid digit for a base, not a digit, x and a..f are not lowercase
> 4. Must use proper subprogram calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems pretty straightforward - read numbers as a string and convert them into integers and add them up. Your convert_number function would need to handle decimal, octal or hexadecimal numbers. First, you'd read the first character - if it's a digit between 1..9, it's decimal. Otherwise, read the second character and check if it's a 'x'or not to decide between octal and hexadecimal. Save the base of the `base` of the number in a variable.

To convert the string to decimal:

1. initialize `number = 0`.
2. read one `digit` of the number. If the `digit` read is `\0`, exit. Otherwise, convert the ASCII digit to a number between `0...9`.
3. `number *= base`
4. `number += digit`
5. go to 2

Once you have this `convert_number` function in place, all you need to do is use it to write a program along these lines.

```
.data
array: .space 1024
.text

main:
    # input & convert string 1
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, array
    li $v0, 1024
    syscall
    jal convert_number
    move $t0, $v0

    # input & convert string 2
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, array
    li $v0, 20
    syscall
    jal convert_number
    move $t1, $v0

    # add numbers and print
    addi $a0, $t0, $t1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    # exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

In MIPS, the convention for writing functions is to put arguments of functions in register `$a0` to `$a3` (we used `$a0` here to send the string address). The values are generally returned using `$v0` and `$v1` (here `$v0` returns the number after converting). There are conventions for what function preserves what registers, but that doesn't really come into play here since we aren't really using nested functions.